# Caching mongoose objects with Redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, redis, mongoose

Is it possible to cache, say, mongoose document obejcts in Redis,
perhaps for implementing a write-back or write-through cache with timeout-based cache flush mechanisms?

P.S.:
I am familiar with [mongoose-redis-cache](https://github.com/conancat/mongoose-redis-cache), but I guess it supports only lean queries, which do not quite serve the purpose here. (But I may be wrong).

Comment: Are you wanting to only write to MongoDB, when a redis key is about to expire? Notificaions are only in a development version of redis (http://redis.io/topics/notifications).

Comment: Precisely, the new API would be awesome, but I was actually thinking of a background job - to check manually for timeouts, to do the trick for me (set keys to expire at, say x time, actually expire them at x-5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mongoose objects wrap a MongoDB document, there'd be no reason that you couldn't call

```
JSON.stringify(mongooseObject.toJSON())
```

which would return a string representing the MongoDB document. ([toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON)) You could then store that result in a key/value in redis.

Where it starts to get more complex is that you'd need to first override the normal `save` and `update` functionality to save any modifications to your redis store rather than to the database. While doable, Mongoose wasn't designed for that and you'd be probably more successful to just use the native mongodb drivers and manage general document interactions that way. There are a number of extremely handy operators that you'd need to independently handle (like `$push` for example, which would add a single value to an array).

The real issue though is that you loose nearly all of the power of MongoDB by not being able to use the query engine or aggregation framework if all of the data isn't already stored in MongoDB (and even if it is, you're still bypassing your caching layer). And, if you're not using any of that functionality, then MongoDB may not be the best match for your needs (and you might instead consider something like CouchDB).

While I can see the potential value of using a caching layer for a high performance MongoDB system,  the complexity of a write-back style cache may be more complex than it's worth (and not necessarily safe).

Of course, a write-through cache would be simpler (although you have the complexity of two data-stores and making sure writes are committed consistently if you're going to trust the cache and DB).

(As an aside, I'm not sure how you'd actually manage timeouts, as I thought redis deleted the values associated with keys if they were assigned a lifetime/timeout? I wouldn't want to loose data to the redis cache if you were doing write-back).

Comment: Mongoose does support 'pre' middleware for 'save' allowing objects to be saved to Redis first before committing to mongodb (write-through), however looks like 'find' / 'exec' where cache hits from Redis can be really helpful in case of mostly-read data, does not support middleware :( (and adding a method to mongoose.Model seems cheap :P )
That aside, a write-through would ensure persistence of the data in mongo while making fetching faster, and in which case, even if the Redis data would get deleted, it might actually do more good than harm.

Comment: Ack. I meant write-back and typed write-through. Write-through would be of course simpler. But, you're talking about all but the most simple fetching (documents by key only). Added a bit more detail.

Comment: Indeed, write-back might not be a good idea after all. Well, write-through and method overrides it is.. and if `mongoose.Query.prototype.execFind` is overridden and `__v`  versioning taken care of, $push etc will probably not break (anyways that needs more code-digging). Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

In Redis you can only cache raw JSONs, but to cache the whole Mongoose.Documents objects, You can use my library, which handles both - caching results in Redis and mongoose documents in memory. It also has event-based logic to clear both caches, if some related changes appear.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/speedgoose